# Total month to date for last year until a specific day of the month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to calculate the sum of MTD sales per day for the same period of last year, only until a specific day - the day of the last sales transaction.

So for example, if the filter is  year= 2019 and month= 2, I need the MTD sales for february 2018 until the 5th, calculated day by day:

```
MTDSales=
VAR MyDay = 5
RETURN
CALCULATE(
  TOTALMTD(SUM(Sales); Calendar[Date]);
  SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(Calendar[Date]);
  //here I need another filter to stop on the 5th!
)
```

Edit:

Please have a look at [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kgMljUVeI6QYVXuvP8_kLCjr6AZU1yVR/view?usp=sharing) to see the sample data.

The measures I'm trying to build are:
Sales MTD CY
Sales MTD LY
Sales MTD CY*
Sales MTD LY*
Sales MTD CY**
Sales MTD LY**

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using 5 since today is February 5th.

You can get `MTDSales` for the current month like this:

```
MTDSales = 
VAR DateRange = DATESBETWEEN( Calendar[Date], EOMONTH(TODAY(), - 1) + 1, TODAY() )
RETURN CALCULATE( SUM( Sales ), DateRange )
```

To match that up with the previous year, just use `SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR`.

```
LastYearMTDSales = 
VAR DateRange = DATESBETWEEN( Calendar[Date], EOMONTH(TODAY(), - 1) + 1, TODAY() )
RETURN CALCULATE( SUM( Sales ), SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DateRange) )
```

---

If you want to use a different date than `TODAY`, just specify that date as a variable and pass it into the `DateRange` variable where `TODAY` appears.

---

If you want to find the `MTDSales` up to the 5th day of the month (assuming you have the month in your filter context), try this

```
MTDSales = 
Var MyDay = 5
VAR MyDate = MIN( Calendar[Date] ) + MyDay - 1
VAR DateRange = DATESBETWEEN( Calendar[Date], EOMONTH(MyDate, -1) + 1, MyDate )
RETURN CALCULATE( [Sum of Sales], DateRange )
```

Then for the previous year, you can reuse that measure, but shifted:

```
PrevYearMTDSales = 
CALCULATE( [MTDSales], ALL( Calendar ), SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR( Calendar[Date] ) )
```

---

**Edit:** After looking at your PBIX, I realized that I had made the wrong assumption about your filter context. Since you are looking to write a measure at the date level, try this instead:

```
Sales MTD CY =
VAR MyDay = 5
VAR CurrentDate = MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
VAR MyDate = EOMONTH ( CurrentDate, -1 ) + MIN ( MyDay, DAY ( CurrentDate ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        TOTALMTD ( SUM ( Sales[Sales] ), 'Calendar'[Date] ),
        FILTER ( 'Calendar', 'Calendar'[Date] <= MyDate )
    )
```

The previous year measure can still be done referencing this measure and shifting.

Comment: Hi Alexis, thanks again for your help! It's a nice expression and it works well, But, in a table where 'Date' is in rows, it shows the total for the month. I need to have the calculation day by day (thus preserving the 'Date' filter somehow. Also, the 5th is not today, it's just a coincidene.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. I've edited my question to provide sample data, please have a look.

Comment: Oh, you had specified a year and month filter context, but in your file, it looks like you are working within a date/day filter context as the lowest level for your table. That definitely changes how to write the measure.

Answer (score 0):

Replace my column names for yours and it should work
The formula remains the same:

```
MTDSales = 
VAR MyDay = 5
RETURN
CALCULATE(
  TOTALMTD([total sales], 'Calendar'[DateKey]),
  SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Calendar'[DateKey]),
  FILTER(
      ALL(Sales),
      Sales[DateKey] >= STARTOFMONTH('Calendar'[DateKey]) && Sales[DateKey] <= DATEADD(STARTOFMONTH(Sales[DateKey]),MyDay-1,DAY)
      )
    )
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for helping! In a table where 'date' is in rows, I get blanks for this measure.

Comment: You mean blanks for rows that aren't between the first 5 days of the month?

Comment: Actually, I get blanks in every cell.

Comment: It's working for february but not for january nor current year (2019). I'm editng the question to provide sample data, please have a look at measures Sales MTD CY** and Sales MTD LY** which are using your expressions. Thanks